# Django 1.8.5 allauth and project app conflicting names

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-1.8

I have a django app called account, which has a custom user model built into it and then I used django allauth for adding social login functionality. Now the problem is that in the settings.py file the follwing app names are conflicting:

1. myproject.apps.account
2. allauth.account

The above throws the following error:
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Commenting any of the above apps in my settings.py, resolves the error. I used https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#for-application-users to change the allauth verbose app name, but I am not being able to resolve this error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: show exactly what you have done

Comment: What files would you like to see so I know what exaclty to post? There is not any code to show as two names are conflicting in the INSTALLED_APPS file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. I solved this problem. Django all-auth has an app with a label `account` and I have an app named `account`. When I put both these apps in my INSTALLED_APPS settings, I get a conflicting error, which is masked by the django error - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady. How I solved this problem:

I used a custom app config for my project app as below and added a different app label, which solved this problem:

```
class ConfigAccount(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_project.apps.account'
    label = 'my_account'
    verbose_name = 'account'
```

The label property makes sure that names do not conflict.

Comment: Did you change anything in installed apps ?